# LMGTFY link can't be added

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments, quality-filter

I tried to paste a link to lmgtfy.com as the comment and I got this error:

> [image: l]

Why is LMGTFY considered bad and are there any other types of content comments can't contain?

Comment: This is entirely *intentional*.

Comment: Tons of [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=lmgtfy) on MSE about this, can't immediately find the post where it was officially announced as blacklisted.

Comment: @OGHaza: [Ban LMGTFY (let me google that for you) links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650) is marked 'status-completed' by Jeff Atwood. It means he agreed and implemented it without further wasting a post on his decision.

Comment: Was it so hard to add `site:stackoverflow.com` to your Google query and picking a suitable dupe target?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+lmgtfy+links

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's not allowed because it is (or, at least, tends to be perceived as) rude and condescending.

Look at it from the recipient's point of view: You go to someone for help, they say "look here", and all that turns out to be is a link to a Google search page.

Rather than a LMGTFY link, if you want to help someone improve their search skills, it is reasonable to leave a comment along the lines of "you need to search for `x y z`".

There are other words and phrases that are not allowed in comments for similar reasons, but it would be counterproductive to tell everyone what that content is.

Comment: Well, it would be not just a link to a search form, but (hopefully) a promising search expression, which might be anything but obvious. Why letting everyone know what content is deprecated/disallowed (not limited to comments) entirely escapes me - to the contrary, I'd welcome a link to pertaining meta-discussions.

Comment: @greybeard - in that case just leave a comment along the lines of "you need to search for `x y z`"

Comment: I think that if the first link it sends you to is the right one it should be allowed. From a programmer's perspective, proper google searching techniques is one of the strongest skill sets you need. Anyone who asks a question that can be asked to google and find a better answer than I can write in 10 minutes deserves that response.

Comment: @Sethmr And if the first link changes to something *not* useful? Then not only is telling someone to look at the first Google result rude, but it is also potentially vulnerable to something resembling link rot.