# Suggested edit queue is full. How to remove a suggested edit from queue?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

When I hover on edit, it shows '*Suggested edit queue is full*'. Where can I see the edit queue? Can I discard my own suggested edit?

Comment: What post (or posts) were you trying to edit when you saw this?

Comment: I did some reviewing earlier today, and unfortunately had to reject one of your edits. I once [proposed a FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/812149) for editors. It is not an official FAQ, but I believe you may find it useful.

Comment: I don't believe "duplicate" (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full) even remotely answers "How to remove suggested edit from the queue"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Since the only other answer is "you can't", my logic for suggesting it was the phrase "Go encourage 2k+ users to start reviewing edits in the queue" from the answer, combined with an explanation as to why the error was popping up was as good an answer as you could realistically get.

Comment: What do you mean by "discard a suggested edit?" Do you mean retract one you proposed, discard someone else's suggested edit, or get some people's edits approved or rejected?

Comment: Asking people not to downvote is usually counterproductive. Besides, votes on Meta don't affect your reputation. The worst that could happen is a question ban on Meta, and for that, you'd have to have several really bad questions.

Comment: Down-voting can help people easily down the morale of the person asking question. Some people just don't know the answer so they habitually down vote the question...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To see how many edits there *approximately* are in the queue, simply go to https://stackoverflow.com/review, and look at the entry for "Suggested Edits".

This number is approximately the total number of pending edits - your edits and those of others. It is an approximation, because the number of edits in the queue changes at a high speed.

You cannot retract edits you've made. You can edit the posts further, until each of your edits is fully reviewed.

The Suggested Edit queue has a maximum size of 500 edits, in total. It is often full. One of the reasons for this is that many people make edits.
For this reason, I advise that when you make an edit suggestion, you try to fix as much as you can. Do not fill up the edit queue with small edits - make your edits significant.

Comment: I've seen the number "206" suggested edits last week, but didn't made a screenshot: I thought it was because the queue size had been increased.

Comment: @Cœur http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @DidierL As that site is 500x more sarcastic that LMGTFY I'm surprised it hasn't been blocked yet.

Comment: @MDXF LMGTFY is blocked [because it is rude and condescending](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255399). I don't think it's the case with shouldiblamecaching, it's just a joke…

Comment: @DidierL Good point

Comment: Can't clear your own queue? Why?

Comment: For those who are >2k, Is it possible to skip an edit during revision? I have four edits that have been sitting there for almost a week. I want to redact them. I have a feeling that people neither approve nor reject them.