# Can I retract a suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I read [this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348727/suggested-edit-queue-is-full-how-to-remove-a-suggested-edit-from-queue) about the limitation of the total suggested edits. Also, I saw on the [review queues page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) the number of suggested edits is changing (So, it is not full).

I edited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646859/daemons-vs-regular-processes-linux-os) on Saturday which has been closed and my suggestion is still pending. Now, I can't edit a new question because the editing queue is full.

What can I do to remove my suggested edit for the closed question and be able to edit new questions ?

Comment: I don't think you can. Once you have submitted the edit, it will stay in the queue until it's been reviewed. I'm not sure, but I think you can modify your edit as long as it's not been handled yet, but that doesn't remove it from the queue.

Comment: There is nothing you can do - there is simply no process for removing edit suggestions - you will have to wait until the number of items in the queue subsides enough. Also, it's the end of the week, so the activity is obviously lower. P.s. In the future, please, avoid editing closed posts *unless your edit resolves the problems that led to closure in the first place*. In this particular case, the question should've been asked on SU - you can't change that with an edit, let it get roomba'd in time.

Comment: See the linked Q&A: "You cannot retract edits that you made. You can edit them further, until they get reviewed."

Comment: Maybe also useful: [Cancel edit before it gets approved](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280891)

Comment: @OlegValter The question was not closed when I edited it and it is why I wanted to delete it, I think nobody will approve an edit on a closed question. So, if I understand I can't do anything...

Comment: @Tom this topic did not answer to my question, it was about the total suggested edits, not the limitation for one person or what happens if nobody approve an edit

Comment: @Julien - yeah, you already did as much as you can by bringing it up on Meta (in terms of getting the edit approved/rejected. I don't see anything wrong with the edit, so I hit approve, but it is likely that it will be rejected). As for the time of edit - I see, well, then please flag the question as off-topic the next time you see one and move on, there is no need for improving what's inherently off-topic.

Comment: @OlegValter Thank you for your help. Maybe it will be approved or delete a bit later

Comment: @Julien Your question is about canceling your own edit and that question answers that. If can't add a suggestion because the queue is full or because you already used your limit is not important for that matter.

Comment: @Julien I've cast a final rejection vote. Not because it is a bad edit, but because the question is unsalvageable. Nobody will really benefit from it, while approving it will also send this question into the reopen votes review queue, which would be a waste of time for those reviewers. Let's leave it for the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: I just saw it. At least, it is not pending now. Thank you

Comment: As a side note, I used to be confused about what is on and off-topic. These helped me most to understand it: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/), [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/) and [How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/) and all the pages in the help center about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)..
and [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)..